# Session timeout and session valid discrepancy

Tags: session, timeout, logout

I have salesforce on a TV as a Dashboard and right now I'm having troubles with the session.

I set my configuration for 24 hours timeout on Session Settings, for the whole org, but if I log and look at Session Management, the session is Valid Until 2 hours ahead. Since this is a Dashboard, thus no user input is made, it logs out the user after 2 hours instead of 24.

Am I configuring it in the wrong place? How can I have the specified behavior?

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gkNxAAI

Comment: As well as timeout can be defined at profile level which override the org default

Comment: Thanks, so by that documentation I can adjust how long before the session timeout message appears, but not the Valid Until part? I want sessions to be 24 hours long, not two...

Session timeout: "Length of time after which the system prompts users who have been inactive to log out or continue working."

Comment: Session expires is the same as valid until. As Avijit said, check the profile for the user.